Custom average merge multiple GeoTIFFs using Rioxarray, Rasterio and Numpy
I'm trying to merge multiple GeoTIFFs using rioxarray merge_arrays with a custom method that averages overlapping values.
I've pieced together the following code which produces a GeoTIFF but it looks like all the values come up as nan.
# Merge with averaging
# Ref: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372957/merge-with-custom-method-in-rasterio
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rioxarray import merge

# test data
item_hrefs=['https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/13/T/DE/2021/3/S2A_13TDE_20210302_2_L2A/B08.tif', 'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/13/T/DE/2021/3/S2A_13TDE_20210319_0_L2A/B08.tif']

nir_rasters=[]
for i in item_hrefs:
    nir_rasters.append(rioxarray.open_rasterio(i, masked=True))
    

def custom_merge_avg(old_data, new_data, old_nodata, new_nodata, index=None, roff=None, coff=None):
    old_data[:] = np.mean( np.array([ old_data, new_data ]), axis=0 )

nir_merged = merge.merge_arrays(nir_rasters,method = custom_merge_avg)

nir_merged.rio.to_raster("nir_merged.tif")


Changing the line
old_data[:] = np.mean( np.array([ old_data, new_data ]), axis=0 )

To
old_data[:] = np.nanmean( np.array([ old_data, new_data ]), axis=0 )

Did the trick.
